# Get variables from .LESS markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, less

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and would like to create a page that lists a .less file's variables and their values as textboxes. My goal is to make a small page that lets you edit their values.

```
 public JsonResult GetLessVariables()
    {
        var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("~/some.less");

        /*  
            Create key value pair of variable and value from file
                i.e
                   @body-color, #000000
                   @text-color, #ffffff
        */

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Is there some easy way to get them into a key value pair dictionary or similar?

EDIT: Example of .less file:

```
//
// Test
// --------------------------------------------------

    @body-color:     #000000;
    @text-color:     #ffffff;


    // Test
    .test {
        background: @body-color;
        color: @text-color;
    }
    ....  and so on
```

Comment: Does the .less file contain only variables? No other markup?

Comment: Edited with example of Less

Comment: If you have your variable names, then you can replace them via Regex, If you write them accurately it'd be a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file only contains variable definitions, you could match the variables with a quick-and-dirty regular-expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>@\w+)\s*:\s(?<value>[^;]+;");

var less = File.ReadAllText("style.less"));

var matches = regex.Matches(less);
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        match.Groups["name"].Value,
        match.Groups["value"].Value));
}
```

Untested, may require tweaking, but should suffice if you can keep the markup simple. If you add a constraint to match whole lines, you can probably get away with running it on your sample, but you risk capturing variables nested at different scopes - a regex is not a good tool for complex syntax.

If you can't move the variables to their own file or add constraints, you'll have employ a much more complex grammar parser to extract the variable declaration statements.

It may be that the [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) project has a parser you can make work for you.